# update model from database not updating code

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model in my website which was generated from a database. When I right click on the edmx diagram to update the model when I have made changes in my database (using mySQL), the model doesn't update the vb code file with any new tables and properties. I am using the standard .tt templates. Isn't the code supposed to regenerate every time the model is updated in this manner?

Comment: If memory serves, when you ask it to update, it expects YOU to select which new tables to add. It updates tables that exist in the model already but doesn't choose which new tables to add (you may not want them all).

Comment: Yes I click on the tables to add. I changed the code generation to default and that now updates the code. The problem is that now the code doesnt see the new properties in the tables. ie user.newtablecolumn generates an error even thought the model updated and there is a property for it. Every time i change the model i have to delete the current one from my app_code folder and add a new whole model for it to work. That shouldn't be.